# Design Over XML Message Creation In Java

Tags: java, xml

I need your inputs to take decision.

Requirement: Maximum I have to send 1000 individual  xml meesages daily to destination.I will get the data from database through result set

object.This component is synchronized,so one request will take place any time.

TO prepare xml message I have 2 options:

1) Prepare one xml message with some xml tags based on result set data and convert it to doc and transform to other xml using xslt.

2) Prepare xml message with String Builder.

Which option in above is more efficient interms of memory and perforamnce.

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: I suggest you use StringBuilder, it takes care of memory

Comment: sorry, it wasn't clear.. at all! you send the xml (strings?) to some component, it gets inserted into the db, then you make a db request and you get the result of the processing? So you are asking a efficient way to contruct xmls? are you using jaxb? xstream? you manipulate your strings by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never build XML "manually" using strings or StringBuilder. Use a proper tree API such as JDOM, DOM4J or a streaming alternative such as Stax. 1000 messages per day doesn't sound like a load that require pre mature optimisations (unless the messages are really, really huge).

Comment: thanks @forty-two.Prolem with first approach is first it will convert it into doc then  xslt compile and transforms 1000 times.In this case memory and perormance both will impace right?

Comment: @user2610401 please clarify you question because i thought the alternatives where related to the construction of the xml and not a post-processing using xslt

Comment: I clearly mentioned in first option,i have to convert to the client format using xslt.

Comment: Given your load, you have almost a minute and a half to process each message. That's an eternity. How large are they, roughly?

Comment: And, why can't you build the target format directly, instead of using an XSLT transformation?

Comment: you bean by using stringbuilder and concatenation? .these are not very big docs

Comment: based on some conditions from databse data,some of the xml tags and it values are different

Comment: @user2610401 and why a xslt transformation ONLY in the first option?